# Get parameter types of all function overloads

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Assume I have a class `bar` with multiple implementations of method `foo`:

```
struct bar {
    void foo(int, int);
    void foo(float, bool);
    void foo(const vector<void*>&);
}
```

Is there a possibility for me to obtain a list of lists of arguments' types? In other words, I define

```
template<typename... types> class list {};
```

and want to obtain `list<list<int, int>, list<float, bool>, list<const vector<void*>&>>`.

Comment: Ah, the mythical `invocation_traits` proposal...

Comment: @KerrekSB that doesn't sound much relieving...

Comment: What kind of interface are you expecting ? Like just provide `bar` and get the `list` ? Well,....

Comment: I don't think you can do it. Even if you could, the usefulness of such a thing is very limited. How would you dynamically construct a call to one of those functions in the list? It can be done with assembly, but I see no other way.

Comment: @SvenNilsson For example, I could dynamically create wrappers for all those functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You can ask the question "can I call `bar.foo` with args `int, long`?".  You can ask the question "is there a `&Bar::foo` method of type `void (Bar::*)(int, int)`?", but neither match your requirements.

Another thing you can do is *perfect forward* into `bar.foo`, and even do SFINAE testing so failure to forward results in a failure at the forwarding interface, not within its implementation.

If you have a finite list of types and max arg count, you can exhastively search the set of overloads for the ones that work, or for exact signature matches, at O(T^N) cost.

As an editorial, your question has the usual flaw with questions of this type, where you describe a particular technical challenge and fail to even casually describe the problem this challenge is intended to solve.  It is actually shocking how reliable the "I want to reflect on function signature overload" questions never, ever volunteer what the particular problem their reflection is intended to fix.  Many, many such problems have solutions that full reflection is not required to solve.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I consider asking a question about my particular problem now. But there is the other side of the coin: my particular problem is way too specialized for asking at SO (I can't even come up with a title short enough), and it will look a lot like "please write the code for me".

Comment: @TigranSaluev I find it best to describe what is blocking you along your path to the fix *and* at least a vague description of why you are trying to do what you are trying to do as efficient.